# Filtering messages on one of thousands of values in AWS - event-driven architecture

Tags: amazon-web-services, microservices, amazon-sns, aws-event-bridge, event-driven

We are working on a system in which one microservice publishes an event on a bus and many others microservices are subscribed to that bus.

Some of the subscribed microservices want to filter the messages so that they only receives events where one of the attributes on the message contains certain values. EventBridge and SNS both provide filtering capabilities, however in this case neither of the built in filtering solutions will work as the number of values for a single attribute we want to allow through the filter is on the order of thousands, simply too big for a SNS filter policy or an EventBridge rule filter.

**Main Question: Can any built in AWS services filter messages when an attributes value is one of a predefined list of 1000s of possible values? If not are there any other services we could spin up ourselves that could accomplish this?**

More details below but above is the true question.

One possible solution is to send every event from the central bus into the subscribing microservices and then process them on entry (in a Lambda for instance) before forwarding along those that meet the filter. This causes issues when deployed at scale however, if there are 25M messages flowing through the event bus each day and there are 10 microservices that each only want to filter messages where an attribute is one of 1000 particular values that would mean that each microservice would receive all 25M messages before filtering out the ones it wants to act on. This corresponds to 250M messages receives to only process a small fraction of them, which seems wrong.

Another possible solution is to condense those 1000 values a particular microservice is interested in down to a single value that can be added as extra data in the metadata of the message and then filter on that using built in SNS or EventBridge filtering. The main question with this approach is where to put that logic that adds the new metadata. The first place that jumps to mind is the producer of the message simply adds the metadata there, but this has a few drawbacks. First it is coupling the producer to consumer as now the producer has to have knowledge of the consuming microservice(s) filtering requirements. Second, if there are multiple places where the event could be published from (not true in this particular case but we will need to possibly adopt this for other messages which could have decentralized producers) then they would each need to be updated to add the filter data.

To remove this coupling we could create a ‘data enricher’ microservice which sits between the published and the main event bus. Messages would be sent to a bus/topic the data enricher is subscribed to, the enricher would then process the message, attach any required metadata and then publish the  message on the shared bus that all other microservices are subscribed to. It would expose some sort of API to all the consuming microservices to be able to register  how they want data enriched; messages of typeA with attr1 equal to v1 | v2 | v3 | … | v1000 get enriched with filterMetadata: [filterId1]. Then the consumer who registered that enrichment will create a simple filtered subscription where filterMetadata contains filterId1.

That should work and is looking like our likely solution, but it adds complexity to the entire system so we are hoping to find a better solution. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Also I used very generic dumbed down numbers and ‘examples’ here, let me know if more detail is required.